# Upload Image from Google drive folder to (wordpress) website folder using Google Apps Script

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script that is connected with the web app to upload images to a Google Drive folder, here is a code snippet for this:

```
function uploadImageToDrive(file, folder) {
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRow = getActiveRow(sheet);
  var imageName = sheet.getRange(activeRow,3).getValue() +"-"+sheet.getRange(activeRow,5).getValue()

  var blob = Utilities.base64Decode(file);
  var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(blob, 'image/jpeg', 'uploaded_image.jpg');
  var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  file.setName(imageName);
  var image = '=image("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id='+file.getId()+'",1)';
  sheet.getRange(activeRow,22).setFormula(image);
  sheet.getRange(activeRow,23).setValue(file.getUrl());
  return 'Image uploaded successfully!';
}
```

Now I want to upload those images to my wordpress website folder. Currently, I do this by following 2 steps:

> 1. Download all images from Google Drive
> 2. Use Filezilla to transfer all images to the site folder

My site folder looks like this:

[image]

I need your suggestion if it is possible to automate this process and directly **upload images from Google Drive to the website folder** using Google Apps Script. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: I think that Filezilla is a FTP client. If your site is required to upload the files with the FTP protocol, unfortunately, in the current stage, Google Apps Script cannot use it. So, about the specification of your site, how about confirming whether the files can be uploaded with the HTTP request? If the file can be uploaded with the HTTP request and your site can be accessed from Google, I guess that Google Apps Script might be able to be used.